# How to get the latest timezone of the system dynamically?

Tags: java, multithreading

After running this application, if I am changing the time zone in between the running application, still the `calendar.getTimeZone()` is not getting the latest time-zone, rather it is displaying the time-zone what was there at the time of running the application:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Test implements Runnable {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("starting");
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    new Thread(new Test()).start();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    new Thread(new Test()).start();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    new Thread(new Test()).start();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    new Thread(new Test()).start();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    new Thread(new Test()).start();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    new Thread(new Test()).start();
    }

@Override
public void run() {

    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    TimeZone t=calendar.getTimeZone();
    System.out.println("from run:"+t.getID());
}
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't run in UTC? If you do that, no such thing as changing timezones. :D

Comment: yes it is the requirement ,at the time of running the application if anybody can change the timezone then we need to shutdown the application thets why

Comment: What platform are you running on? How is the time zone being changed?

Comment: in java environment  , some scenario is there ,if you have any solution could you please write a code ..u can use utc also

Comment: Maybe you need: `TimeZone.setDefault(null)`, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-

Comment: I meant, is this supposed to work on Windows? or Linux? or what? How is the time zone being changed on that OS?

Comment: Could you please better describe what you want to achieve? A1) start your application, A2) change the timezone of the system --> your application should be notified about this change, B1) start your application, B2) the user change the timezone for the application --> all date/time related computation should use the new timezone.

Comment: A1>start the application,  a2> while running the application change the timezone  it means ,run a thread which will  run continuously ,and then change the timezone before the application stops the execution ,and see the thread can able to detect the timezone change or not.

Comment: @jyotisman Have a look at my updated answer. There is a (more straight forward) solution without using reflection.

Answer (score 4):

By default the timezone is set only a the JVM start. If the OS timezone is changed during the application execution this is not automatically forwarded to the JVM. But you can force a re-read of the current timezone.

Following example was tested as-is only in a Windows environment.

1. start the `TestTimeZone`
2. during the execution change the Windows timezone from `Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region` - `change the time zone`

.

```
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestTimeZone implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("starting");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            new Thread(new TestTimeZone()).start();
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(null);
        System.setProperty("user.timezone", "");
        System.out.println("current OS timezone: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
    }
}
```

**example output**

```
current OS timezone    : Europe/Berlin
current OS timezone    : Africa/Windhoek
current OS timezone    : Europe/Helsinki
current OS timezone    : GMT
...
```

**edit** The above code works also on Linux (below steps where tested on Debian, CentOS).

During the execution of `TestTimeZone`, execute as `root` (execute with a short delay between the single steps).

```
$ timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Berlin
$ timedatectl set-timezone Africa/Windhoek
$ timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Helsinki
$ timedatectl set-timezone GMT
```

**note** Before changing your timezone make a note of your current.

```
$ cat /etc/timezone
```

Comment: Thanks for replacing that horrific copy/paste code with a simple loop.